# C++ template for generating parts of switch statement?

Tags: c++, templates, switch-statement

Is it possible to write a template

```
Foo<int n>
```

such that:

```
Foo<2>
```

gives

```
switch(x) {
  case 1: return 1; break;
  case 2: return 4; break;
}
```

while

```
Foo<3>
```

gives

```
switch(x) {
  case 1: return 1; break;
  case 2: return 4; break;
  case 3: return 9; break;
}
```

?

Thanks!

EDIT:

changed code above to return square, as many have guessed (and I poorly asked)

Comment: Is it really for computing a square? (And discarding it.)

Comment: What are 1, 4 and 9 in your example? Should that be the 'return value' of the switch? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: C++ templates have often been compared to fancy macros and can often replace traditional macros for some applications, but they aren't macro preprocessors. Also, since there's no observable behavior from  your `switch` statements, the examples you posted probably aren't great examples of what you might really be looking to achieve. You might want to describe what your overall goal is - it might be possible to have templates do what you want, just not in the way you might be thinking about at the moment.

Comment: btw you dont need those `break` s after a `return` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, make a template with an oversized master `switch` and hope/help the optimizer turns it into a little `switch`. See my answer to your other question [Runtime typeswitch for typelists as a switch instead of a nested if's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157149/runtime-typeswitch-for-typelists-as-a-switch-instead-of-a-nested-ifs). Also, don't duplicate-post.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) to evaluate the result of the `switch` if the value you're switching on (in this case, `x`) is not known at compile time.  This is because templates are blown-out at compile-time, not at run time.

However, if you know the value at compile-time, you can achieve a similar effect:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int V> struct intswitch
{
    operator int() const
    {
        return V * V;
    }
};

int main() {

    cout << "1 = " << intswitch<1>() << endl
        << "2 = " << intswitch<2>() << endl
        << "3 = " << intswitch<3>() << endl
        << "4 = " << intswitch<4>() << endl
        << "5 = " << intswitch<5>() << endl
        << "6 = " << intswitch<6>() << endl
        << "7 = " << intswitch<7>() << endl
        << "8 = " << intswitch<8>() << endl
        << "9 = " << intswitch<9>() << endl
        << "10 = " << intswitch<10>() << endl
        ;
}
```

Program output:

```
1 = 1
2 = 4
3 = 9
4 = 16
5 = 25
6 = 36
7 = 49
8 = 64
9 = 81
10 = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort-a, kind-a, not really.  You can get something close to the behavior you are asking for although not done with an actual switch.

Okay, I'm assuming `foo<N>` means the ability to calculate the square of any value between 1 and N but no other values.  So, I came up with this:

```
template <int t>
int foo(int x)
{
    return (x > t)   ? -1 :
           (x == t)  ? (x * x) :
                       foo<t -1>(x);
}    

template <>
int foo<0>(int x)
{
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The runtime complexity is... bad. Why using another template if `x < t` ? In the end, as long as `x` is in `[0,t]` you'll get `x*x` as a result, no need to go recursive there.

Comment: Neat answer. It's like a linear lookup time switch, but clever.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need a lookup table for something like that mate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are actually looking for templates here, but rather macros. Try [this reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) for info on the C preprocessor, which *may* be able to do what you want. Templates work on types, and aren't suited to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but I believe templates can work on values. That's why the `typename` keyword exists: to create templates that work on types.

Comment: Indeed, for example to compute a square at compile-time `template <int N> struct square { static const int value = N * N; }`. They don't generate normal switches, although it might be possible to set up a compile-time switch with template meta-programming (loops and if's are doable, so I don't see why a switch shouldn't be) - but it is hard to see what the OP wants to achieve in the first place.

Comment: Templates work on values as well. Their most come use is for types though.