Automatic template instantiation in C++?
The codebase I work on nowadays is heavily optimized. In that spirit, functions often taken bool or enum template arguments and then use if constexpr to branch on them. The point is, we can ensure that in tight loops where we process millions of items, the function really only has code that's actually needed. For example:
template<bool use_filter> void foo(Items& items) {
  if constexpr (use_filter) {
     if (!filter(items)) return;
  }
  process(items);
}

Obviously, the actual functions are way more involved, but the above example demonstrates how this is used. Problem is, now we have code that looks like this:
  if (query.use_filter()) {
    foo<true>(items);
  } else {
    foo<false>(items);
  }

It's actually much worse, as we have often multiple template arguments so the if-forest grows quite large. What's intriguing is that what I really would like to write is foo<query.use_filter()>(items). That is, somehow tell C++ to turn a runtime value into a template argument by implementing the branching automatically under the hood. Yes, it's code explosion, but we're already doing that. It's possible to use macros to achieve this (to some extent), but it gets quite ugly quick. It'd be better not to use macros.
Question: is this possible without macros? It's doable with macros, I know that.

" somehow tell C++ to turn a runtime value into a template argument..." Not possible

Can you also add a [mcve]. We need exact code whose alternative you want. Like you said that it's possible with macros, so show us how it is possible with macros.

" would like to write is foo<query.use_filter()>(items)..." This is not an option if use_filter is not constexpr etc. Basically, query.use_filter() must be a compile time constant.

So basically, you've optimized certain functions to take compile-time parameters, and now you want to un-optimize them so they can take runtime parameters? (Instead of an if inside the function, it's now outside.)

JaMiT: No, I'd like C++ to do the if-branch expansion that I have to do manually. I want to keep the compile-time boolean parameters.

Quasi duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68831855/, just with bool instead of int.

One way to turn runtime value into compile time value is with std::variant and std::visit:
constexpr std::variant<std::true_type, std::false_type> as_bool_type(bool b)
{
    if (b) {
        return std::true_type{};
    } else {
        return std::false_type{};
    }
}

and then
std::visit([&](auto b/* possibly other param */){ foo<b /* .. */>(items) },
           as_bool_type(query.use_filter()) /* possibly other variant..*/);


You can create something like std::visit for values. I call this "compile time promote", it's in Boost.Mp11 as mp_with_index (which is for std::size_t but you can easily use it with bool):
// Boost version
boost::mp_with_index<2>(query.use_filter(), [&](auto use_filter) {
    foo<use_filter>(items);
});

// No boost version
template<typename F>
constexpr decltype(auto) constexpr_promote(bool b, F&& f) {
    if (b)
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::true_type{});
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::false_type{});
}

constexpr_promote(query.use_filter(), [&](auto use_filter) {
    foo<use_filter>(items);
});

And for enum arguments, you can basically reimplement boost::mp_with_index:
enum E { ..., Count };

boost::mp_with_index<std::size_t{E::Count}>(get_enum(), [&](auto enum_val) {
    f<E{enum_val}>();
});

// No boost version
template<typename T>
const T get_max;
template<typename T> requires (std::is_enum_v<T>)
inline constexpr T get_max = T::Count;
template<typename T> requires (std::same_as<T, bool>)
inline constexpr T get_max = true;

template<typename T, T val = T{}>
constexpr decltype(auto) constexpr_promote(T v, F&& f) {
    if constexpr (v == val) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::integral_constant<T, val>{});
    } else if constexpr (v != get_max<T>(val)) {
        if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) {
            return constexpr_promote<T, T{std::to_underlying(val) + 1u}>(v, std::forward<F>(f));
        } else {
            return constexpr_promote<T, val + 1u>(v, std::forward<F>(f));
        }
    } else {
        std::unreachable();
    }
}
constexpr_promote(get_enum(), [&](auto enum_val) {
    f<enum_val>();
});


Sure!  It is honestly easier if you rewrite your template functions a bit, however.
template<bool b>
using bool_constant = std::integral_constant<bool, b>

template<bool use_filter>
void foo(bool_constant<use_filter>, Items& items)

This helps call foo more directly without having to mess with passing parameters both as template and non-template arguments.
Then we write this toy:
using kbool = std::variant< bool_constant<false>, bool_constant<true> >;

a kbool has two possible states corresponding to false and true.
kbool evaluate( bool b ) {
  if (b) return bool_constant<true>{};
  else return bool_constant<false>{};
}

std::visit( [&](auto kb) {
  foo( kb, items );
}, evaluate(query.use_filter()) );

we convert our runtime bool into a std::variant over false/true, then pass that to foo using std::visit.
You can pretty this up however you want.
The underlying type being a bool is optional; it can be any finite enumeration (integers over a range, or an enum).
The kbool at runtime is literally an integer whose value is 0 if false and 1 if true.  We just dress it up into type that lets us do stuff like std::visit.
You could even wrap foo up so it takes a kbool and does the std::visit internally; this wrapper could even dispatch bool_constants directly without std::visiting.
Then
foo(query.use_filter(), items);

becomes how it is used at point-of-use.
The wrapped up foo is either written manually like:
template<bool b>
void foo(bool_constant<b>, Items& items) {
  // code
}
void foo(kbool kb, Items& items) {
  return std::visit([&](auto kb) {
    return foo(kb, items);
  }, kb);
}

or you make some machinery to make this easier, like
const auto ffoo = kwrap( OVERLOADS_OF(foo), tag<kbool> );

which generates a ffoo callable object that does the above for 1 kbool compile-time parameter around a base function foo.

template<bool> void foo() {}

void do_foo(bool b)
{
   using foo_t = void (*)();
   static const foo_t funcs[] = { foo<false>, foo<true> };
   funcs[b]();
}

That's it. No variants, no boost, no nothing.
What about an integer template parameter? It is a bit tiresome to write foo<0>, foo<1>, foo<2>, ..., foo<256>, right? Not a problem either:
template<std::uint8_t> void foo();

using foo_t = void (*)();

template <std::size_t ... x>
constexpr std::array<foo_t, sizeof ... (x)>
reify_foo_helper(std::index_sequence<x...>)
{
    return { foo<x> ... };
}

template <std::size_t limit>
constexpr std::array<foo_t, limit> reify_foo()
{
    return reify_foo_helper(std::make_index_sequence<limit>());
}

void do_foo(std::uint8_t u)
{
    static constexpr auto foos = reify_foo<256>();
    return foos[u]();
}

It's a bit disconcerning that you need to reify every function template separately this way, because C++ lacks non-type template template parameters. But if you stop writing standalone function templates and start writing classes with static templated member functions uniformly named run, all is well again.
// fully generic part starts

template <typename C, std::size_t ... x>
constexpr std::array<decltype(&C::template run<0>), sizeof ... (x)>
reify_helper(std::index_sequence<x...>)
{
    return { &C::template run<x> ... };
}

template <typename C, std::size_t limit>
constexpr auto reify()
{
    return reify_helper<C>(std::make_index_sequence<limit>());
}
// fully generic part ends

struct Foo
{
    template<std::uint8_t>
    static void run();
};

void do_foo(std::uint8_t u)
{
    static constexpr auto foos = reify<Foo, 256>();
    return foos[u]();
}

Bounds checking omitted for the sake of exposition.
